# declaring a pointer or a stack variable

Tags: c++, c++11

Assume we have the following case:

- If it is morning mood is good otherwise mood is bad
- Print the mood

it could be written as:

```
std::string mode; //this cost us calling the constructor of std::string
if(time==Morning){ // a real code should be here
   mood="Good"//re assign the string
}
else{
   mood="bad"//re assign the string
}
std::cout << mood;
```

assuming it is not std::string, it is a very big object. Isn't it too luxury to declare "mode" and call the constructor for no reason! 
Is using the raw pointer a solution? what is the best practice here?
thanks

Comment: Or `std::cout << (time == Morning ? "Good" : "Bad") << std::endl;`. No need to create a string object.

Comment: 1. whenever thinking about runtime costs: measure first, than change the code if necessary. 2. it depends - measure how really costly it is in your case (your 'costly' object)

Comment: If you mean will something like `Type& ref = (condition ? obj1 : obj2);` will be more efficient than creating a default construction of a third object and conditionally firing the copy-assignment operator, very likely yes. Whether that fits your needs is an entirely-different issue.

Comment: I wouldn't sweat it. With the small-string optimization, the ctor of the empty string only sets a few members. They'd be on the stack at fixed offsets. Flow analysis by the optimizer will show that these members are directly overwritten regardless of the branch taken, so all code generated by that first constructor is effectively optimized out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) to initialize the string.

```
std::string mode = (time == Morning ? "Good" : "Bad")
```

As  [MSalters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15416/msalters) pointed out in the comments this is actually still two constructions(constructor + copy) but it should get optimized by the compiler.  You can directly initialize the string with

```
std::string mode { (time == Morning ? "Good" : "Bad") };
```

Comment: Technically it's still two (conversion ctor followed by copy ctor), but that's typically optimized by the compiler. The direct method is `std::string mode { (time == Morning ? "Good" : "Bad") };`

Comment: Not at all, StackOverflow content is all under Creative Commons license precisely because we encourage mixing of contributions to get the best answers.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider putting the logic into a separate function. This helps to keep functions small and simple.

```
std::string moodAtTime(Time time)
{
    if(time==Morning)
    { // a real code should be here
        return "Good";
    }
    else
    {
        return "bad";
    }
}

std::string mood = moodAtTime(t);
```

This reduces function length and splits the code into small units performing simple questions.

If it is only for initialization, you can use a lambda to do it without the named function:

```
std::string mood = [](Time t)
{
    if(t==Morning)
    { 
        return "Good";
    }
    else
    {
        return "bad";
    }
}(now);
```

Answer (score -1):

The cost gets high if you enter that specific scope allot of times, and yes, it could get very expensive (depending on the what's happening inside the scope) .

The solution would be to keep either a global variable, or more widely used, a pool of such objects (object pools / memory are widely used for such purposes, especially in the case of small and very small objects).

So, to explain in code

```
 // scope that is entered allot, like 100k times per second
 {
   std::string temp;
   ...
   // magic happens
   ...
 }
```

Quick solution

```
 {
    static std::string g_uniqueNamed_temp_string;
    ...
    // magic happens
    ...
 }
```

Elegant solution

EDIT : switched to raw pointers to avoid copying

```
 {
   std::string* tempString = StringPool::GetAPreallocatedString();
   ...
   // magic happens
   ...
 }
```

Comment: This is not how C++ works. The "quick solution" must check whether the static is already initialized. Because it's not on the stack, the check must be done in a threadsafe manner. Synchronization is not fast. The "elegant solution" takes a preallocated string _and copies it_. That's worse than the first case, which only creates an empty string. On modern C++ compilers, this (1) moves the stack pointer and (2) sets a length field to zero (which is on the stack and therefore in cache). Two CPU operations which are both extremely fast.

Comment: Valid point, but imo besides the question ! If you read carefully ,the OP said clearly that he just exemplified with std::string, and that in the real case scenario things are much more complex(a very big object), which leads me to speculate that instead of std::string there is an object which requires a much more complex initialization (such as reading from a file). I still stand by my argument that memory pools, pre-intializations and other techniques to avoid repeated allocations in a scope are used , and should be used allot in C++, and this is what i was exemplifying.

Comment: You do make a point regarding the copy  in the "elegant" solution , especially considering that the techniques which I wanted to exemplify are returning pointers, not objects, so I will modify my answer. Regarding the sync of the static object : a very large object allocation isn't faster then the threadsafe access of the variable ... assuming that there's a threading issue to start with!

Comment: It doesn't really matter to the stack whether you're allocating 20 or 2000 bytes. And the compiler cannot assume there are no threading issues, it has to assume there are.

Comment: Ok , and assuming they are, what will the compiler do ? I honestly don't get how can an (unsafe in case of multi threading) global variable access can be more expensive then a complex object construction... From what you're saying I'm missing some knowledge regarding what compilers do under the hood when a global variable is accessed. Would you mind explaining to me or  giving me a link or some pointers ?

Comment: Not global, function-level `static`. This is important because these can only be constructed when the function is first called. At that time multiple threads may very well exist. What the compiler will do is unspecified; just that the result is race condition free. Typically an initialization flag is checked. This read must be done using a memory fence.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `alloca` for that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std::literals;
int main() {
    void *mem = alloca(sizeof(std::string)); //Allocates memory on stack; no initialization
    std::string *mood;
    if(true){ // a real code should be here
        mood = new (mem) std::string("Good");//re assign the string
    }
    else{
        mood=new (mem) std::string("Bad");//re assign the string
    }
    std::cout << *mood;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your declaration is an array having length 1 and _is_ constructed.

Comment: `std::string mode = alloca(sizeof(std::string));` What?!? There's all sorts of broken here...

Comment: Allocating an instance of a class using `alloca` will not call a constructor, unless the `alloca` implementation internally uses `new` which is, at best, doubtful. So the instance of the string points to a blob of memory which is not constructed and you have undefined behavior. If it works, it's from sheer luck. See: http://ideone.com/19Pe5C

Comment: You have not - the `std::string` constructor never runs in your example and the pointer points to a blob of memory large enough to hold a string, but one that _does not_ contain a constructed `std::string`. The assignment results in undefined behavior.

Comment: While the ctor is now fixed it still is less efficient than putting `mood` on the stack straight away. Also, don't forget that `alloca` fails to call the destructor of `std::string`. That's a second more serious problem.

Comment: @MSalters For class with complex construct it might be still efficient to call `alloca` instead of 1 more constructor.

Comment: @Randl: The usual examples involve a class which cannot be default-constructed at all. Still, see NathanOliver's answer to have a single ctor call.

Comment: @MSalters Ternary operator won't work if you need to do something before assignment.

Comment: @Randl: In that case, consider Jens' solution (named function or lambda). Alternatively, use the comma operator. Really, that's 4 options which are better than this hack.